# Using shell for loop deal with json

Tags: shell

Here is my shell code,My question is I don't want the ',',at the end of json file.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATCH_VERSION_FILE=/root/workspace/patch_version.json
filepath=/root/workspace/txtdir
for file in "${filepath}"/*.txt; do
    echo "    {" >> ${PATCH_VERSION_FILE}
    filename=`echo ${file} | awk -F'/' '{ print $(NF) }'`
    filemd5=`md5sum "${file}" | awk '{ print $1 }'`

    echo "    \"${filename}\"":"\"$filemd5\"">>${PATCH_VERSION_FILE}
    echo "    },">>${PATCH_VERSION_FILE}
done
```

Output:

```
{
"2001.txt":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
},
{
"2002.txt":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
},
{
"2003.txt":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
},
{
"2004.txt":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
},
{
"2005.txt":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
},
```

I found a soulution,but it looks ugly,the code below:

```
n=0
for file in "${filepath}"/*.txt; do
    if [ $n -ne 0 ];then
        echo "    ," >> ${PATCH_VERSION_FILE}
    fi

    echo "    {" >> ${PATCH_VERSION_FILE}
    filename=`echo ${file} | awk -F'/' '{ print $(NF) }'`
    filemd5=`md5sum "${file}" | awk '{ print $1 }'`

    echo "    \"${filename}\"":"\"$filemd5\"">>${PATCH_VERSION_FILE}
    echo "    }">>${PATCH_VERSION_FILE}
    n=$(( $n + 1 ))
done
```

but the ',' not the same line with '}',is there any ways to deal with this ?

Comment: If you show the input JSON and expected output, you might get much better answers using suitable tools such as `jq`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add this at the end of your script (after your for loop). It will simply remove (actually will replace with empty string) the last character of the file :

```
sed -i '$ s/.$//' $PATCH_VERSION_FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to have valid JSON data, you can use a JSON aware tool like `jq`:

```
md5sum "$filepath"/*.txt | jq -R 'split("  ")|{(.[1]):.[0]}' >> ${PATCH_VERSION_FILE}
```

`-R` option allows `jq` to read strings from `md5sum`.

The string is splitted in 2 and then assigned to the key/value object.